# Using Azure functions output in an HTML file

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I use my Azure function to return a certain output after passing an HTML trigger. The webpage prints out basic output, like `Hello {name}`.

I would like to pass this output into an HTML file and display it via a separate HTML file. Essentially, I want to extract what my `helloworld.azureapp.com?name={name}` returns and push it into a JS variable in an HTML file.

How would I do this?

Note that the Azure function is written in Python.

Comment: Could you share the input html and desired output html examples?

Comment: Is you web application written in JavaScript or python? If so which python framework?

Comment: The webapp is written in JS, and the function is written in Python.

Comment: Which framework in javascript? React? Vue?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what you're looking for is to make your web application send a GET request to your azure function endpoint and store the response you get back in a javascript variable.

You should treat the responses from an Azure function HTTP trigger just like any standard response from any API.

Instead of writing all js code in native HTML files, it is recommended you pick a simple web application framework.

For python, you can try Django or Flask (introductory tutorials [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-build-a-web-application-using-flask-and-deploy-it-to-the-cloud-3551c985e492/)).

The code that calls your Azure function endpoint `helloworld.azureapp.com?name={name}`
 could be in your web application (using the `requests` module in python). Tutorial on how to make web requests in python [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/getting-started-with-python-requests-get-requests).

Once you get back the response for that request, you can do further processing with the values you get back.

Depending on your web application framework, you could do many things.

Some of them are:

1. Save it in a hidden field and get value in JavaScript.
2. Render the received values to element in page on server side and show it.